# Multiple NavigationPages Outside of MainPage

Tags: maui

We are mostly a WPF shop currently and are exploring MAUI development for future projects. We have a need to track three separate layers of content (in addition to any necessary modal content), which each navigate and may all be visible on the screen at once.

I am attempting to work through various use-cases in a test app, and am separating cases in a TabBar. I had thought to use three NavigationPages in the VM of one tab and navigate each independently, but I am stumbling over getting even one to work, let alone three.

I have tried several different approaches, including ContentPresenter and ContentView, but here is the core of my most recent approach:

```
public NavTestVM()
{
    NavPage = new NavigationPage(new NavRoot());
}

<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MauiAndUnitTest.Views.NavTest"
         x:DataType="viewModels:NavTestVM">
    <TemplatedPage ControlTemplate="{Binding NavPage.CurrentPage}" HeightRequest="400" WidthRequest="600"/>
</ContentPage>

<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MauiAndUnitTest.Views.NavTestViews.NavRoot"
         BackgroundColor="Coral">
</ContentPage>
```

The NavRoot page (the root page in NavPage) does not appear in the tab. If, in App.xaml.cs, I replace

```
MainPage = new AppShell();
```

with

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new NavRoot());
```

I get a page full of Coral-y goodness on startup. What am I missing to get current NavigationPage content to display, outside of App.xaml.cs.MainPage?

Assuming I can get this working, I would then expect I can just repeat the approach twice more for the other layers and call it good.

Comment: generally you would make your MainPage a TabbedPage, and then each tab would contain a NavigationPage, and each NavigationPage would contain a ContentPage that is the root for each tab's Navigation stack

Comment: I have seen this in the examples on MSDN, but it doesn't satisfy our need for multiple simultaneously-visible nav stacks. I also fail to understand the mechanism by which the TabbedPage knows to display its child NavigationPage's CurrentPage, as opposed to any other visual content in the TabbedPage.

Comment: if you need them to be visible at the same time you're going to have to write your own solution.  Nothing built in allows that

Comment: the TabbedPage displays the NavigationPage for the selected tab.  The NavigationPage maintains its navigation stack and determines which "current" page to display

Comment: If all three are visible at the same time, then thay are not "Pages"; a `Page` fills the screen (window). How would you have done this in WPF (within a single window)? You could add WPF code to question; that would make it easier to find Maui equivalents, or explain what elements to put together. Consider not using Maui's built in AppShell. replace `MainPage = new AppShell();` with `new` of a custom page containing 3 ContentViews. Then manipulate the contents of the ContentViews.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I get that the docs say that a Page fills the screen, but the framework itself ignores that with tabs. I have a working version of what I have done in WPF - it involves multiple ContentPresenters and a homegrown state machine. The purpose of this question is to try and figure out how to do it "the MAUI way." I want to make use of the built-in Navigation properties of pages, which is why I have not pursued ContentViews.

Comment: *"the framework itself ignores that with tabs"* Good point. So there must be *some* internal way to "carve out" a space that a Page goes into. You'd still have to invent the top-level layout that can hold multiple NavigationPages, and direct all navigation to the correct one. I suspect that would be more work than working with ContentViews. Either way, you have to "roll your own" navigation scheme.